# Who do I get all explain plans for a period of time?

Tags: oracle

How does one get all the explain plans for all the queries running on an Oracle database?

Will

```
 alter session set statistics_level = 'all;
```

do the trick?

Comment: No. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To find queries that have bad explain plans during a period of time in a system with multiple queries

Comment: How do you determine a bad explain plan? If you are looking for poorly executing SQL, does not the runtime (wall clock) tell you? You can also generate an AWR (Automatic Workload Repository) report for the offending period.

Comment: Multiple queries are running during the test period. I was hoping to use the ASH/AWR reports to pin point of time and queries to examine. After that, with all the gathered explain plans I could then narrow down to the offending queries.

Comment: The test takes many hours and I would like to collect as much data as possible

Comment: You probably want to collect SQL Monitor reports, as opposed to explain plans anyway, since this will give you the runtime information necessary to evaluate performance. An AWR can be collected over the entire run.

Comment: The explain plans would be helpful to fix the queries

Comment: Explain plans are only sort of useful. They do not necessarily give you the *actual* runtime execution plan. Also, in order to get an explain plan, you have to run the Explain Plan command on each SQL. SQL Monitor is "always on".

Comment: How do I get the explain plan for every SQL query, Where do I access the SQL monitor? Is that a part of the basic Oracle Database

Comment: I'm not a licensing expert, but you need the Oracle Tuning Pack. From the Doc, this is a cost option unless you are using one of the Cloud products. SQL Monitor is available in the Cloud Console, Enterprise Manager, EM Express or can be run at the SQL command line.

Comment: @BobC - Thanks you for the insights. Is there a way around not paying for getting the explain plans. The data must? be in the database. and the products just extract it

Comment: A few options I can think. 1, you can manually explain all the statements. If you have all the SQL, that is fairly easily scripted. 2. You can turn on 10046 trace, all though tracing itself will impact performance.